# How to attach a template to an existing file in VBA/Word?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I created a Word file "test.word" that was saved in a C directory.
I would now like to execute a template on this explicit Word file using the VBA function, and using the inserted button macro which
is already set up.

What should the macro look like for this? I've tried a lot, either I have to create a completely new file or the command takes the template directly ... but not the "test.word" file.

**Document.Add** creates a new Word file. **Document.Open** uses the template as a file.
**Document.AttachedTemplate** gives runtime error 4198.

Is my project even possible?

Code:

```
Sub RufeVBVfg()
        documentObject.AttachedTemplate = "C:\VB\VBVerfuegung"
End Sub
```

Comment: See What is the Relationship Between a Microsoft Word Document and Its Template before proceeding too far. http://shaunakelly.com/word/templates/templaterelations.html Attaching a template will give you access to macros but will not insert any content including a macro button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set the template of a new file:

```
Documents.Add Template:="[FULL PATH TO TEMPLATE FILE]"
```

To set the template of an existing `Document` object:

```
documentObject.AttachedTemplate = "[FULL PATH TO TEMPLATE FILE]"
```

For more on `AttachedTemplate`, please see https://learn.microsoft.com/sv-se/office/vba/api/word.document.attachedtemplate

Comment: @MartinHe No, sorry - is there an error message other than the number?

Comment: it throws a runtime error 424 “Object Required”. what kind of object do I have to specify?

Comment: @MartinHe We would need to see more of the code in order to help - please update above or post a new question.

Comment: Thx for your help. Actually, I just want to execute this function and load a template by clicking a button in Word.

Comment: i guess, it was my bad. ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate seems to work. ^^